# aws-amplify | Can't reexport the named export 'package_name' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I'm trying to use the `aws-amplify` node package in my mini-programs project. However, when I try to run `import Amplify, {API} from 'aws-amplify`, I get the following error:

> Can't reexport the named export 'package_name' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

I have tried to depreciate the npm package `aws-amplify` to a older version as Mini-Programs run on the previous version of NodeJS.

After doing some research on the issue, I found a [solution](https://www.qualityology.com/tech/webpack-graphql-compile-error-easy-fix/) that recommended to add the '.mjs' extension to the `webpack.js` config file. However, being sub-app on the VodaPay environment - I don't have access to the `webpack.js` file.

```js
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      'node_modules',
    ],
},
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some npm packages are not compatible with mini programs due to them not having access to the DOM.

The AWS amplify package isn't compatible because of this. It makes use of the fetch() JavaScript function which isn't supported in the mini programs.

By just importing the package into an empty mini program I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
```

Comment: Will fetch be included into a future version of Mini-Programs?

Comment: No. You need to make use of of the my.request function to make requests to external services